# IO Other Operations Performance Counter Explanation

Tags: performance, winapi, disk, perfmon

I have received perfmon counters from customer site. We noticed unusual values in `\\COMPUTERNAME\Process(PROCESS_NAME)\**IO Other Operations/sec**`.

The best explanation for the counter I came up with is:-

> The average rate at which the process
>   is issuing I/O operations that are
>   neither read nor write operations (for
>   example, a control function). This
>   counter counts all I/O activity
>   generated by the process to include
>   file, network and device I/Os. This
>   counter is equivalent to the perfmon
>   counter Process\IO Other
>   Operations/sec.

On [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490957.aspx), its description does not appear.

Who knows what this counter `(**IO Other Operations/sec**)` actually counts? Which system call may cause this counter to be increased and how it can be monitored.

We are working with C++.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a documented list of operations exist as it is too broad. However, you can use the [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) tool to find out what operations are performed by a running process in real-time. If you watch the movement of the I/O Other Operations metric of a process (such as in the Task Manager - Details tab with added column "I/O other"), while having  Process Monitor running with a filter on the process PID, this should give you good indications on which operations affects the counter.